# Stored procedure Is throwing ORA-20000: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: oracle, plsql

The below code is used to create the stored procedure and this is how the stored procedure is called. Stored procedure is throwing ORA-20000: ORA-00913: too many values

```
BEGIN EDW_ODS_DELETE_RECORDS_PKG.MAIN('EDWFIN', 'PSP_LABOR_ADJUSTMENTS_F'); END;
```

```
create or replace 
    PACKAGE BODY         "EDW_ODS_DELETE_RECORDS_PKG" AS
    
    CON_EDW_IUD_FLAG  CONSTANT CHAR := 'D';
    CON_CURRENT_FLAG  CONSTANT CHAR := 'N';
    CON_DELETED_FLAG  CONSTANT CHAR := 'Y';
    PROCEDURE main (table_schema_in   IN VARCHAR2, target_table_alias_in   IN VARCHAR2) AS
      v_source_schema       VARCHAR2(30);
      v_source_table_name   VARCHAR2(30);
      v_target_schema       VARCHAR2(30);
      v_target_table_name   VARCHAR2(30);
      v_source_table_key    VARCHAR2(1000);
      v_target_table_key    VARCHAR2(1000);
      v_table_type          VARCHAR2(20);
      v_last_deleted_date   DATE;
      v_delete_control_id   NUMBER := 0;
      v_target_table_alias  VARCHAR2(30);
      v_arc_target_table_name   VARCHAR2(30);
      BEGIN
          SELECT SOURCE_TABLE_SCHEMA, SOURCE_TABLE_NAME, SOURCE_TABLE_KEY,
                  TARGET_TABLE_SCHEMA, TARGET_TABLE_NAME, TARGET_TABLE_KEY,
                  TABLE_TYPE, LAST_DELETED_DATE, DELETE_CONTROL_ID,
                  TARGET_TABLE_ALIAS,
                  ARC_TARGET_TABLE_NAME
                  INTO
                  v_source_schema, v_source_table_name, v_source_table_key,
                  v_target_schema, v_target_table_name, v_target_table_key,
                  v_table_type, v_last_deleted_date, v_delete_control_id,
                  v_target_table_alias,
                  v_arc_target_table_name
                  FROM EDW_ODS_DWH_DELETES_CONTROL
          WHERE target_table_schema = table_schema_in AND target_table_alias = target_table_alias_in;
    
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Values : ' || v_last_deleted_date);
    
          v_source_table_key := REPLACE(v_source_table_key, '~', ' || ''~'' || ');
          v_target_table_key := REPLACE(v_target_table_key, '~', ' || ''~'' || ');
    
          IF v_table_type = 'FACT' THEN
            UPDATE_FACT_TABLES (v_source_schema, v_source_table_name, v_source_table_key,
                                      v_target_schema, v_target_table_name, v_target_table_key,
                                      v_last_deleted_date, v_delete_control_id,v_arc_target_table_name);
          ELSE
            UPDATE_DIMENSION_TABLES (v_source_schema, v_source_table_name, v_source_table_key,
                                      v_target_schema, v_target_table_name, v_target_table_key,
                                      v_last_deleted_date, v_delete_control_id, v_table_type);
          END IF;
    
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            ERROR_LOG(v_delete_control_id, table_schema_in, target_table_alias_in,
                        SQLERRM, DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
            RAISE;
      END main;
    
      PROCEDURE UPDATE_FACT_TABLES (source_schema_in IN VARCHAR2, source_table_name_in IN VARCHAR2, source_table_key_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                      target_schema_in IN VARCHAR2, target_table_name_in IN VARCHAR2, target_table_key_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                      last_deleted_date_in IN DATE, delete_control_id_in IN NUMBER, arc_target_table_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
    
      v_source_stage_table        VARCHAR2(70);
      v_target_fact_table         VARCHAR2(70);
      v_target_arc_table          VARCHAR2(70);
      query_fetch_deleted_recs    CLOB;
      query_insert_into_arc       CLOB;
      query_delete_from_fact      CLOB;
      v_delete_count              NUMBER;
      v_insert_count              NUMBER;
      v_last_deleted_date         VARCHAR2(100) := TO_CHAR(last_deleted_date_in,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    
      BEGIN
          v_source_stage_table  :=  source_schema_in || '.' || source_table_name_in;
          v_target_fact_table   :=  target_schema_in || '.' || target_table_name_in;
          v_target_arc_table    :=  target_schema_in || '.' || arc_target_table_name;
    
          query_fetch_deleted_recs    := ' SELECT * FROM ' || v_source_stage_table ||
                                      ' STAGING_TABLE WHERE STAGING_TABLE.' || source_table_key_in || ' = FACT_TABLE.' || target_table_key_in ||
                                      ' AND NVL(STAGING_TABLE.EDW_IUD_FLAG, ''X'') = '''|| CON_EDW_IUD_FLAG ||
                                      ''' AND STAGING_TABLE.EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME >= TO_DATE('''|| v_last_deleted_date || ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'')';
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Query : ' || query_fetch_deleted_recs);
          query_insert_into_arc       := 'INSERT INTO ' || v_target_arc_table || ' SELECT * FROM ' || v_target_fact_table ||
                                      ' FACT_TABLE WHERE EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
          query_delete_from_fact      := 'DELETE FROM ' || v_target_fact_table ||
                                      ' FACT_TABLE WHERE EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert Query : ' || query_insert_into_arc);
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_insert_into_arc;
            v_insert_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_delete_from_fact;
            v_delete_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
          COMMIT;
    
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Results : ' || v_insert_count ||v_delete_count);
    
          --IF v_insert_count > 0 AND v_delete_count > 0 THEN
              UPDATE_LAST_DELETED_DATE(v_source_stage_table, delete_control_id_in);
          --END IF;
    
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;
    
      END UPDATE_FACT_TABLES;
    
      PROCEDURE UPDATE_DIMENSION_TABLES (source_schema_in IN VARCHAR2, source_table_name_in IN VARCHAR2, source_table_key_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                      target_schema_in IN VARCHAR2, target_table_name_in IN VARCHAR2, target_table_key_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                      last_deleted_date_in IN DATE, delete_control_id_in IN NUMBER, table_type_in IN VARCHAR2) AS
    
      v_source_stage_table      VARCHAR2(70);
      v_target_dim_table        VARCHAR2(70);
      query_fetch_deleted_recs  CLOB;
      query_update_dim1         CLOB;
      query_update_dim2         CLOB;
      query_update_dim6         CLOB;
      v_update_count            NUMBER;
      v_last_deleted_date       VARCHAR2(100) := TO_CHAR(last_deleted_date_in,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
    
    BEGIN
          v_source_stage_table  :=  source_schema_in || '.' || source_table_name_in;
          v_target_dim_table    :=  target_schema_in || '.' || target_table_name_in;
    
          query_fetch_deleted_recs    := ' SELECT * FROM ' || v_source_stage_table ||
                                      ' STAGING_TABLE WHERE STAGING_TABLE.' || source_table_key_in || ' = DIM_TABLE.' || target_table_key_in ||
                                      ' AND NVL(STAGING_TABLE.EDW_IUD_FLAG, ''X'') = '''|| CON_EDW_IUD_FLAG ||
                                      ''' AND STAGING_TABLE.EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME >= TO_DATE('''|| v_last_deleted_date || ''', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'')';
          IF table_type_in = 'DIMTYP1' THEN
          query_update_dim1           := 'UPDATE ' || v_target_dim_table || ' DIM_TABLE' ||
                                      ' SET DIM_TABLE.DELETE_FLAG = ''' || CON_DELETED_FLAG || ''', DIM_TABLE.EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME = SYSDATE, DIM_TABLE.EDW_UPDATED_BY = ''ETL'''||
                                      ' WHERE (DIM_TABLE.DELETE_FLAG = ''N'' OR DIM_TABLE.DELETE_FLAG IS NULL)' ||
                                      ' AND EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Query : ' || query_update_dim1);
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_update_dim1;
              v_update_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    
          ELSIF table_type_in = 'DIMTYP2' THEN
          query_update_dim2           := 'UPDATE ' || v_target_dim_table || ' DIM_TABLE' ||
                                      ' SET DIM_TABLE.CURRENT_FLAG = ''' || CON_CURRENT_FLAG || ''', DIM_TABLE.EDW_END_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE), ' ||
                                      ' EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME = SYSDATE, EDW_UPDATED_BY = ''ETL'''||
                                      ' WHERE DIM_TABLE.CURRENT_FLAG = ''Y'' AND EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
    
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_update_dim2;
              v_update_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    
            ELSIF table_type_in = 'DIMTYP6' THEN
            query_update_dim6           := 'UPDATE ' || v_target_dim_table || ' DIM_TABLE' ||
                                      ' SET  DIM_TABLE.EDW_END_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE) , ' ||
                                      ' DIM_TABLE.DELETE_FLAG = ''' || CON_DELETED_FLAG || ''', DIM_TABLE.EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME = SYSDATE, DIM_TABLE.EDW_UPDATED_BY = ''ETL'''||
                                      ' WHERE DIM_TABLE.EDW_END_DATE = TO_DATE(''12/31/2099'',''MM/DD/YYYY'') AND EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
    
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_update_dim6;
              v_update_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    
          END IF;
          COMMIT;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Results : ' || v_update_count);
    
          --IF v_update_count > 0 THEN
              UPDATE_LAST_DELETED_DATE(v_source_stage_table, delete_control_id_in);
          --END IF;
    
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;
      END UPDATE_DIMENSION_TABLES;
    
      PROCEDURE UPDATE_LAST_DELETED_DATE (source_stage_table_in IN VARCHAR2, delete_control_id_in IN NUMBER) AS
      query_max_updated_query   CLOB;
      v_max_updated_date        DATE;
      BEGIN
          query_max_updated_query := 'SELECT MAX(STAGE_TABLE.EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME) FROM ' || source_stage_table_in || ' STAGE_TABLE ';
    
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_max_updated_query INTO v_max_updated_date;
    
          UPDATE EDW_ODS_DWH_DELETES_CONTROL
                  SET EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME = SYSDATE, EDW_UPDATED_BY = 'ETL', LAST_DELETED_DATE = v_max_updated_date
          WHERE DELETE_CONTROL_ID = delete_control_id_in;
    
          COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;
      END UPDATE_LAST_DELETED_DATE;
    
      PROCEDURE ERROR_LOG (delete_record_key_in IN NUMBER, table_schema_in   IN VARCHAR2, target_table_in   IN VARCHAR2,
                              error_message_in IN VARCHAR2, error_backtrace_in IN VARCHAR2 := NULL) AS
    
        PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN
          INSERT INTO edw_ods_dwh_deletes_log VALUES (delete_record_key_in, target_table_in, table_schema_in, SYSDATE, 'ETL',
                                                        error_message_in, error_backtrace_in);
          COMMIT;
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, error_message_in);
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE;
            END ERROR_LOG;
    END EDW_ODS_DELETE_RECORDS_PKG;
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to expect us to decipher. What debugging have you done? For a start the full exception will tell you the object and line number it's complaining about. (From a very quick scan, I'd guess the problem is your dynamic `insert ... select ...` - do your source and target tables have the same number, data type and order of columns?)

Comment: @AlexPoole This is the error message I am getting                                              
 ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06512: at "SUODS.EDW_ODS_DELETE_RECORDS_PKG", line 298
ORA-06512: at "SUODS.EDW_ODS_DELETE_RECORDS_PKG", line 295
ORA-06512: at "SUODS.EDW_ODS_DELETE_RECORDS_PKG", line 85
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Please add significant information to your question as an edit, not as comments. Your code is trapping the real error and re-throwing just the high-level message, with a customer ORA-20000 code. The full error and backtrace should be in `edw_ods_dwh_deletes_log`, if I'm following what's happening. But even with that, look at the relevant line numbers in your package.

Comment: check your `select ... into .... from .... where ....` statements, by removing `Into` part. If it returns more than 1 row, then that is your culprit.

Comment: @Utsav - it's too many values, not too many rows.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is, as the `ORA-00913` error message states, that in one of your statements you are passing too many values.

---

#### Cause:

As an example, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a NUMBER, b NUMBER);
```

And you do either of:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

Then you get the error:

> ```
> ORA-00913: too many values
> ```

As you are trying to insert three values into two columns.

If you name all the columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

Then you will get a more expressive error message:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "C": invalid identifier
> ```

---

#### Solution:

Go through every statement and explicitly name the columns you are inserting and make sure you are selecting the same number of columns.

For example, in the `UPDATE_FACT_TABLES` procedure you have:

```sql
query_insert_into_arc := 'INSERT INTO ' || v_target_arc_table || ' SELECT * FROM ' || v_target_fact_table ||
                         ' FACT_TABLE WHERE EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
```

It would be better to be:

```sql
query_insert_into_arc := 'INSERT INTO ' || v_target_arc_table || ' (col1, col2, col3, col4)
                      || ' SELECT other_col1, other_col2, other_col3, other_col3'
                      || ' FROM ' || v_target_fact_table || ' FACT_TABLE'
                      || ' WHERE EXISTS (' || query_fetch_deleted_recs || ')';
```

Then you know which columns are being inserted where and you will get a more detailed error message if you are trying to insert into a column that does not exist.

---

You also do not need to use:

```sql
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE;
```

As the default behaviour is to rollback the transaction when an exception is raised.

Additionally, you should not raise an exception in your autonomous transaction as you are already raising the exception in the non-autonomous procedure.

```sql
PROCEDURE ERROR_LOG (
  delete_record_key_in IN NUMBER,
  table_schema_in      IN VARCHAR2,
  target_table_in      IN VARCHAR2,
  error_message_in     IN VARCHAR2,
  error_backtrace_in   IN VARCHAR2 := NULL
)
AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO edw_ods_dwh_deletes_log (
    delete_record_key, -- Give the columns their proper names
    target_table,
    table_schema,
    change_date,
    col1,
    error_message,
    error_backtrace
  ) VALUES (
    delete_record_key_in,
    target_table_in,
    table_schema_in,
    SYSDATE,
    'ETL',
    error_message_in,
    error_backtrace_in
  );
  COMMIT;
  -- Remove raising the exception.
END ERROR_LOG;
```